# Is there anyway to tell whether a Service is exported?

Tags: android, service

I'm making a library project which provide an exported Service(It must be exported because other app will use it), I want to make sure anyone who use the library project declare the Service as `exported=true` in `AndroidManifest.xml`, and who do not abide the rule must get a warning. But I don't know how to tell whether it is declared as exported=true or not, does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: PackageManager.getServiceInfo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Use [PackageManager.getServiceInfo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getServiceInfo(android.content.ComponentName,%20int)) to get [ServiceInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ServiceInfo.html), which is subclass of [ComponentInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ComponentInfo.html), having `exported` public variable.***

Use below method to do that

```
private boolean isServiceExported(ComponentName componentName) {
    try {
        ServiceInfo serviceInfo = getPackageManager()
                .getServiceInfo(componentName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        return serviceInfo.exported;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Call it as

```
ComponentName component = new ComponentName("com.anotherapp.pkg", "com.anotherapp.pkg.class_name");
boolean isExported = isServiceExported(component);
```